# How to set type parameter of interface's implementing class?

Tags: java

I want to know if is it possible to set a paramenter's type that is the type of the class that implements a given interface. Seeing some code the question will become more clear:

```
interface A {
 A sum (???? another);
}

class AClass implements A {
    private int internalStuff;

    A public sum (???? another) {
      // I want to access another.internalStuff in a type safe fashion
    }
}
```

Of course I can substitute ???? with A type, and inside AClass.sum, cast it to AClass but that is ugly. Can "????" be replaced with some meaningful type declaration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no self-type in Java, so you have to do a little trick to achieve this.

You can add a type parameter with a recursive type bound to the interface. The implementing class sets this parameter to its own type. Like this:

```
interface A<T extends A<T>> {
    A sum (T another);
}

class AClass implements A<AClass> {
    private int internalStuff;

    public A sum(AClass another) {
        // ....
    }
}
```

There is nothing stopping `AClass` from doing `implements A<SomeOtherAClass>` though. You have to trust the implementing class to provide the correct type parameter.

Comment: You could also use abstract class  with protected variable